# Embedding an instance of InfoPath in a Visual Studio Project?

Tags: vb.net, infopath, embedded-resource

Consider the following mock-up image I've created:

[image: mockup]

I am new with working with InfoPath and I was curious if anyone knows how to embed an instance of InfoPath inside of a winform, so users can fill out the form without launching the InfoPath application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InfoPath editor can be hosted as a control in a Winforms application.  The instructions for doing so are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa947697.aspx, near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

See [Hosting the InfoPath 2007 Form Editing Environment in a Custom Windows Form Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa701079.aspx).